# CSS transform happens instantly

Tags: jquery, css

So I'm trying to get my navBar to move in from the left side (off screen) to the right (next to menu button). The trouble is that while my transition works after I click it twice, one the first click the elements always snaps to position instantly. I've tried using `.css()` and `.addClass()` but they doth end with the same results. I've found a few other posts where people have similar issues, but none dealing specifically with the transition duration.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firstOpen = true;
  var openMenu = false;
  $("#menu-container").click(function(){
    if(openMenu == false && firstOpen == true) // rotate menu button for cool effect
    {
      $("#centered").append("<div id = 'nav-bar-container'> </div");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'home' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'Schedules' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'Media' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'Membership' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'About Us' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#nav-bar-container").append("<div id = 'Membership' class = 'nav-bar-button'> <span class = 'nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      $("#menu-container").css("transform", "rotateZ(-90deg)");
      $("#nav-bar-container").addClass("translate-right")
      $("#nav-bar-container").css("transform", "translateX(20vw)");
      //$("#nav-bar-container").toggleClass("nav-bar-container-clicked");
      //$("#nav-bar-container").css("right", "100vw");
      //$("#nav-bar-container").css("right", "8vw");
      openMenu = true;
      firstOpen = false;
    }
    else if(openMenu == false && firstOpen == false)
    {
      //$("#nav-bar-container").css("right", "8vw");
      $("#nav-bar-container").css("transform", "translateX(-100vw)");
      $("#nav-bar-container").toggleClass("nav-bar-container-clicked");
      $("#menu-container").css("transform", "rotateZ(-90deg)");
      openMenu = true;
    }
    else if(openMenu == true)
    {
      $("#nav-bar-container").toggleClass("nav-bar-container-clicked");
      //$("#nav-bar-container").css("right", "100vw");
      $("#nav-bar-container").css("transform", "translateX(20vw)");
      $("#menu-container").css("transform", "rotateZ(0deg)");
      openMenu = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
}
#menu-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vh;
  right: 3vw;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 6vh;
  height: 6vh;
  border: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.menu-icon {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: purple;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  margin: 1vh;
  transition: .2s;
}
#menu-background:hover .menu-icon {
  opacity: .8;
  background-color: white;
  width: 85%;
  height: 10%;
}
#menu-background:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
#nav-bar-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 65vw;
  transition: .5s linear;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 8vh;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#centered {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 12vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}
.translate-right {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "animations.js"> </script>
    <script src = "velocity.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body id = "body">
    <div id = "centered">
      <div id ="menu-background">
        <div id = "menu-container">
          <div class = "menu-icon"> </div>
          <div class = "menu-icon"> </div>
          <div class = "menu-icon"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "background-container" id = "background-container-1"> </div>
    <div class = "background-container" id = "background-container-2"> </div>
    <div class = "background-container" id = "background-container-3"> </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting the HTML would help.

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the HTML. This is my first post so I apologize If I'm missing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to animate appended elements (I don't know why, by the way...). So that on first click, those do not exist yet.

There was a slight logic inversion were you had the `#nav-bar-container` positionned at `-100vw` when opened and at `20vw` when closed... That happens me all the time ;)

I added a `setTimeout()` for the first translate movement to be executed... Since the append just occured.

I hightly reduced the amount of jQuery lookups on the same element, by getting it in a variable asap in the code... But twice, as you will notice, since before 1st click, it does not exist.

So here is your updated code with a nice result (in my opinion):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firstOpen=true;
  var openMenu=false;
  
  var menu_container=$("#menu-container");
  
  menu_container.click(function(){
    var nav_container=$("#nav-bar-container");
    
    // rotate menu button for cool effect
    if(openMenu == false && firstOpen == true){
      $("#centered").append("<div id='nav-bar-container' style='transform:translateX(-100vw);'> </div");
      nav_container=$("#nav-bar-container");
      
      nav_container.append("<div id='home' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      nav_container.append("<div id='Schedules' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      nav_container.append("<div id='Media' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      nav_container.append("<div id='Membership' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      nav_container.append("<div id='About Us' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      nav_container.append("<div id='Membership' class='nav-bar-button'> <span class='nav-button-text'> </span> </div>");
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        menu_container.css("transform", "rotateZ(-90deg)");
        nav_container.addClass("translate-right")
        nav_container.css("transform", "translateX(20vw)");
      },100);
      
      openMenu=true;
      firstOpen=false;
      
    }else if(openMenu == false && firstOpen == false){
      nav_container.css("transform", "translateX(20vw)");
      nav_container.toggleClass("nav-bar-container-clicked");
      menu_container.css("transform", "rotateZ(-90deg)");
      
      openMenu=true;
      
    }else if(openMenu == true){
      nav_container.toggleClass("nav-bar-container-clicked");
      nav_container.css("transform", "translateX(-100vw)");
      menu_container.css("transform", "rotateZ(0deg)");
      
      openMenu=false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
html{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu-container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
}
#menu-background{
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vh;
  right: 3vw;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 6vh;
  height: 6vh;
  border: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.menu-icon{
  width: 5vh;
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: purple;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  margin: 1vh;
  transition: .2s;
}
#menu-background:hover .menu-icon{
  opacity: .8;
  background-color: white;
  width: 85%;
  height: 10%;
}
#menu-background:hover{
  opacity: .8;
}
#nav-bar-container{
  position: fixed;
  width: 65vw;
  transition: .5s linear;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 8vh;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#centered{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 12vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}
.translate-right{
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="animations.js"></script>
    <script src="velocity.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <div id="centered">
      <div id ="menu-background">
        <div id="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-icon"></div>
          <div class="menu-icon"></div>
          <div class="menu-icon"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background-container" id="background-container-1"></div>
    <div class="background-container" id="background-container-2"></div>
    <div class="background-container" id="background-container-3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your answer was very insightful. I figured the anwer probably had something to do with the elements not existing when the code was called, but I'm still a bit fuzzy as to how that works.

Comment: When I append the elements and THEN perform the animation doesn't that mean that the appended elements must exist in the DOM? Does this mean that there is a sort of delay between my code being executed and the elements actually being added in the DOM? If so, how do I determine the length of delay that is needed before executing the animation?

Comment: Your question really is pertinent. I'm not sure how to reply to that without being wrong. I think that is that it is all about the animation (which as delays) ... If you define it a "state" and right after, define it as another "state"... Like for the translateX animation... I guess, if it hasn't time to even start the render, it skips to next definition. That isn't technical at all... But following the hint of that feeling, I fixed the issue. So... Is that intuition? ;) Be good!

Comment: On a little additionnal effort from me to reply to your acurate question... And about  something more "technical"... I'm sure that `transition: .5s linear;`, from `#nav-bar-container` CSS rule, has to do with the need of a `setTimeout()`. ;)